# Count number of individual lines from a text file c#

Tags: c#

I have a text file with 14000 lines however many of these are duplicates. I want to count the unique lines, however i only have access to framework 3.0 and below. Is it possible to do this without using.linq?

Comment: Is the file "sorted" (ie are the duplicates one after another or are they anywhere in the file) ?

Comment: Framework 3 does support LINQ, right? Did you check and can you be specific about Fx and C# versions?

Comment: No they're all over the place

Comment: @HenkHolterman maybe it does but i dont want to use it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: No, it doesn't. LINQ was introduced in .NET 3.5.

Comment: And does it have to work on 1.x as well? Makes a big difference.

Comment: I'm using 3.0 and blow I cant use any higher.

Comment: That's not the answer we need here. Do you use versions below 2.0 ?

Comment: You could use, ilSpy - on a newer project, and se how they do it in linq :)

Comment: Linq doesn't enable new things to happen, it's just a grammar for expressing your code (gross simplification).  So the answer to that portion of your questions is: Yes.  It's possible.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it's possible, you can loop through each line using `StreamReader.ReadLine` and add each line to a HashTable structure using the line as the key and some dummy object as the value. Before adding the string though, you should check that the HashTable doesn't already have the key:

```
HashTable uniqueLines = new System.Collections.HashTable();
string line;

// Read each line of the file until the end
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
  // Check that we have not yet seen this string before
  if(uniqueLines.ContainsKey(line) == false) 
  {
    uniqueLines.Add(line, 0);

    // You can write the lines to another file in necessary
    writer.WriteLine(line);
  }
}
```

At the end the number of items in the HashTable should be equal to the number of unique lines in the file:

```
int count = uniqueLines.Count;
// And don't forget to close the reader (and writer)!
```

Why does this work? Because the HashTable uses the hash code returned by GetHashCode(0 and according to MSDN:

> If two string objects are equal, the GetHashCode method returns
>   identical values. However, there is not a unique hash code value for
>   each unique string value. Different strings can return the same hash
>   code.

Now I'm not sure how common it is when two different strings have the same hash code, but as I understand many LINQ methods use HashTable internally, so this may be the closest to what LINQ  would do.

Comment: How would i direct this to a file?

Comment: The type or namespace name 'HashTable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) - C:\Users\Stefan\Dropbox\C\Assigment\Assigment\Program.cs:50,3

Comment: @Evildommer5 did you add those namespaces in your .Cs file

Comment: Yes it is, but you need to import the `System.Collections` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I think you also could write it by linq .

```
     var result = from p in File.ReadAllLines(filepath)
         group p by p into g
         select new { Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

It is intelligible.